# A criterion for surjectivety in terms of rank of the differential

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, singularity-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth compact $3$-dimensional manifolds. Assume that $f \colon M \to N$ is a $C^2$-map, such that

1. $\operatorname{rk} \ Df = 3$ in at least one point;
2. if $\operatorname{rk} Df \neq 3$, then $\operatorname{rk} Df = 1$.

Does it follow that $f$ is surjective?

More generally, one can ask about maps of $n$-dimensional manifolds, such that the rank of differential equals $n$ in at least one point, and if it is not $n$, then it is strictly less then $n-1$. My feeling is that in this case the map has to be surjective. The euristic explanation is: since $\operatorname{rk} Df$ is maximal in at least one point, the map is generically open; the image $f(M)$ contains an interiour, and its closure is a $C^1$-manifold with boundary. The boundary is of dimension $n-1$ and for a generic point on it the rank of the differential should equal $n-1$.

However I am not able to find any discussion in the literature, although the topic seems to be pretty classic.

N.B.: The $C^2$-restriction on the map is nut essential; I would be interested in any results for smooth maps as well.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I am not a differential topologist.) Your sketch looks plausible mod details: $M$, hence its image, is compact, so boundary points of the image have preimages in $M$. Compactness is essential: It's easy to construct a smooth counterexample mapping $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ to itself. (Connectedness is also essential, but was surely intended.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang sure, both compactness and connectedness are essential, thank you. I think the most subtle point is the last sequence. The boundary can be rather ugly (I would like to say it is a manifold with corners, but I do not know a reference). Why does generic point has $\operatorname{rk} Df = n-1$?

Comment: In any case, I am so surprised, that such statement cannot be easily found in textbooks (this makes me suspect that it is wrong)

Comment: As you say, the boundary can be ugly; I think it can be worse than a manifold with corners, e.g., the image of the set where $Df$ has rank $1$ can be a snarl of curves, like a Hawaiian earring. The boundary $\partial f(M)$ does separate the interior of $f(M)$ from the complement, has compact preimage, and if $f(p)\in\partial f(M)$, then $Df(p)$ has rank $<3$ (inverse function theorem). Intuitively, if $Df$ has rank $1$ everywhere on $f^{-1}(\partial f(M))$ then $\partial f(M)$ is "curve-like", but I don't have a proof offhand (hence the disclaimer, and the comments rather than an answer).

Comment: I think it would be naturally to restrict everything to analytic category to escape too pathological situations. Although I believe it is also true in smooth category, but the proof might be more complicated